# rename objects in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object

Let's say I have a list named `dogs` containing objects of the `Dog` class. I want to rename each object in the list to the dog's `id` attribute while still being able to modify the objects at each index.

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed, id):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed
        self.id = id

dogs = []

intake = input("Enter the number of dogs to intake:")

for i in range(0,int(intake)):
    name = input("Name of dog: ")
    age = input("Age of dog: ")
    breed = input("Breed of dog: ")
    dog_id = input("Dog ID: ")
    dogs.append(Dog(name, age, breed, dog_id))
```

If you print all the objects in the list, you get something like:

```
[<__main__.Dog object at 0x1234>, <__main__.Dog object at 0x5678>]
```

I want to rename all the objects in the list to the dog id with preserving their attributes.

Comment: make a class `Dogs` which handles list of instances of `Dog` with a `edit_name` method or subclass `list`

Answer (score 1):

```
@dataclass
class Dog:
    name: str
    age: int
    breed: str
    id: int = field(default_factory=lambda: Dog._get_next_id())

    next_id: int = 1  # Class variable to track the next ID

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyClassDog(id={self.id}, name='{self.name}', age={self.age}, breed={self.breed})"

    @classmethod
    def _get_next_id(cls):
        _id = cls.next_id
        cls.next_id += 1
        return _id


dogs = []

intake = input("Enter the number of dogs to intake:")

for i in range(0, int(intake)):
    name = input("Name of dog: ")
    age = int(input("Age of dog: "))
    breed = input("Breed of dog: ")
    dogs.append(Dog(name, age, breed))
print(dogs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off just to use a nested dictionary if you want to access the data using the dog_id.

```
intake = int(input("Enter the number of dogs to intake:"))
Dogs={}
for i in range(0,intake):
    name = input("Name of dog: ")
    age = int(input("Age of dog: "))
    breed = input("Breed of dog: ")
    dog_id = input("Dog ID: ")
    Dogs[dog_id]={'name':name,'age':age,'breed':breed}

#To get a list of all the IDs, you could use Dogs.keys()

print(Dogs[<enter the dog ID here>]['name'])
```

You can access any of name or breed or age using the ID. (Remember the ID should be enclosed in quotations as it is a string, you don't have to if you use int() while getting input for dog_id)

To change a value, you can do the following

```
Dogs[enter the dog ID here]['name' or 'age' or 'breed']= enter the new value
```

Answer (score -1):

for a behavior like that you need to impalement __str__ method on your Dog class
Also you have to print dogs one by on or call str(dog) on each dog

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed, id):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed
        self.id = id
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"


dogs = []

intake = 2

for i in range(0, int(intake)):
    name = input("Name of dog: ")
    age = input("Age of dog: ")
    breed = input("Breed of dog: ")
    dog_id = input("Dog ID: ")
    dogs.append(Dog(name, age, breed, dog_id))

for dog in dogs:
    print(dog)

print([str(dog) for dog in dogs])
```

Comment: lets say i wanted to modify a dog, 

dogs = [id1,id2,id3]

i want to rename "Fluffy" who is at id2

would i just then do something like 

```
dog_to_modify = input("Dog ID or Name: ")

dogs.index(str(dog_to_modify))

```

then call a def set_<attr>(attr)?